# c# BindingList with Dapper

Tags: c#, winforms, dapper, bindinglist

Could someone help on how to use BindingList with dapper 1.60.6 in winforms c#

Here's my code

```
public BindingList<DisplayTransaction> GetTransactionsBinding()
{
    BindingList<DisplayTransaction> result = new BindingList<DisplayTransaction>();
    string sql = @"select * from transaction";
    result = _conn.Query<DisplayTransaction>(sql).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

It keeps saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sales_Monitoring.DisplayModels.DisplayTransaction>' to 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Sales_Monitoring.DisplayModels.DisplayTransaction>"

I tried adding cast to `result = (BindingList<DisplayTransaction>)_conn.Query<DisplayTransaction>(sql);` but I got runtime error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BindingList has a constructor that accepts a `List<T>`

```
public BindingList<DisplayTransaction> GetTransactionsBinding()
{
    string sql = @"select * from transaction";
    var result = _conn.Query<DisplayTransaction>(sql).ToList();
    return new BindingList<DisplayTransaction>(result);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, I forgot to tell that it tells "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Sales_Monitoring.DisplayModels.DisplayTransaction>' to 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Sales_Monitoring.DisplayModels.DisplayTransaction>" in this line of code `result = _conn.Query<DisplayTransaction>(sql).ToList()`

Comment: I tried your code  then got runtime error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Oh, I added parameters after the sql then works like magic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ken your comments are outdated and should be removed